# SQL Server database extent and pages

Tags: sql-server

I want to ask about the SQL Server database, all I know about database structure is that under the database we have datafiles (`.mdf/ndf` & LogFile), then extents, then pages, and each extent contains 8 pages (each page is about 8060 KB in size), also I read about fill factore and understood that to get better performance when editing on tables you have to set fill factore for about 75% or something, and if that table is read-only fill factore could be 95 or 100 (if I'm right).

What I want to know here is that:

1. Is there one extent created for each new table that I create in the database or a table that can read from multiple extents?
2. (if YES, what happens if I make BULK editing [load much more data] on a table and all of its extent pages filled up [all 8 pages], in this case, is there a new Extent creating to hold the new data for the same table, so the table here will read from two extents? or new pages creating an extent so number increased to 9, not 8 pages?

BR,

Comment: To a first approximation, leave `FILLFACTOR` alone and leave it at 0 (or 100, which is the same thing). It doesn't do what most people think it does, and what it does do is useful only rarely. It has no direct relationship to how extents and pages are allocated, in any case (other than the obvious increase in pages when an index is rebuilt). The way extents are allocated for new tables has changed with new versions of SQL Server (and whether you're using a bulk insert), but the pertinent question would be why you think you need to know -- is there an actual problem to solve?

Comment: Each page is 8kb or 8192 Bytes

Comment: Comments should only be used for asking for clarification, or to leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post, or to add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated), or to provide site usage guidance.  See the [help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) for details.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there one extent created for each new table that I create

In modern versions of SQL Server, yes see [Pages and Extents Architecture Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/pages-and-extents-architecture-guide?view=sql-server-ver15)

> is there a new Extent creating to hold the new data for the same table

Yes.  If all the extents for a table are full, a new extent will be allocated for that table.